# Help me with a paradox

Tags: personal-practice, five-precepts, sila

One Day i was thinking about the "Thrikoti parishuddha sila" (The ultimate version of five precepts)

Let me give an example how this version works....

- You can't kill
- You can't aid killing
- You can't hire to kill
- You can't order to kill
- You can't admire / promote killing
- If you can stop a killing you must stop it

*These can be applied to all of the precepts...*

---

So while i was thinking about this and this came into my mind.

If i see an animal getting eaten by another animal what should i do?

If i see a someone having an extramarital affair what should i do?

and so on....

My question is some of these are without doubt only result in a good way but some will give suffering or pain to that person or animal so doesn't that generate bad karma for me??

Comment: Answer to [this question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12235/how-come-sn-goenka-thought-that-buying-milk-does-not-lead-to-suffering) suggests that eating other animals isn't morally wrong from the Buddhist perspective, and only things that actively promote suffering (e.g. killing them yourself) are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I am familiar with the term “pārisuddhi-sīla”, but this only relates to monastic practice (restraint according to Vinaya, restraint of senses, purification of livelihood and restraint in use of the four requisites). I have not heard of the "ultimate version of the five precepts"... where are these mentioned?

Your first five bullet points are mentioned in the Atthasālinī under courses of immoral action (also mentioned in the Vinaya), but I have not encountered “If you can stop a killing you must stop it”. Is this from a Mahāyāna text?

Your questions seem to be around this final bullet point.

Please help me to better understand and I may be able to offer an answer.

Comment: "[Thrikoti parishuddha](http://www.secularsrilanka.com/discussions/taboo/lost-articles-from-taboosubjects-blog/do-good-buddhists-eat-more-meat)" is used to describe meat which a monk "has not (a) seen, (b) heard or (c) do not suspect the animal specially killed for his consumption". Perhaps "the ultimate version" of five precepts are the OP's own musings/speculation/extrapolation.